# How to limit Finder search to only programs?

Tags: mac, search, finder, macos-catalina

In `Finder`, I select the `Programs` Favorite which shows me all programs. Then I input something in the search box to search for a specific program. But instead of searching the search term among the programs, Finder switches to a search among ALL FILES (!) on my MacBook Pro! (Which shows a confusing huge number of files!)
So how can I LIMIT the search to only programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the Mac app "Launchpad" which allows me to search for programs. On the Logitech Craft keyboard, the Launchpad can be activated with the `F4` key. On the `Mac Dock`, it can be activated with the missile icon.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no fast way to modify the defaults of finder search to applications only.

Although, I use spotlight instead, it seems to be much more "clever" and predict what I ment when searching.

Also, I find it convenient to nevigate between programs.

Keyboard shortcut: '<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>'

('<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>' in some other layouts)

[Demonstation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a625k.jpg)